# how to calculate unixtime stamp with ttl in scala

Tags: java, scala, unix-timestamp

hi i want to calculate unixtime stamp with a ttl of 24 hours so that i can use it as a expiry time of 1 day for that i have tried the following code after doing some research

here is my code on scala

```
import java.time.Instant
import java.util.Date
val ttl:Long =24*3600
val unixTimeStamp =System.currentTimeMillis()/1000L + ttl
```

the above produces the output

```
1602071235
```

i just want to know is that the correct way of doing this in scala/java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `java.time` API introduced in **Java 8** you only need to do this:

```
import java.time.{Duration, Instant}

Instant.now.plus(Duration.ofDays(1)).toEpochMilli
```

Comment: @swaheed right, my bad, you only need to call `toEpochMilli` at the end to get the unix timestamp out of the **Instant**, I just edited my answer.